# What will be the host name of websocket on server?

Tags: laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-websockets

I am using laravel websocket in my laravel project. In broadcasting.php, there is pusher configuration like this below:

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => false,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ],
        ],
```

My question is what will be the value of host here when on live server ? My domain is https://test.something.domain.

Also can I keep the port number 6001 on live server as in local ?

Answer (score 0):

based on documentation about broadcasting [pusher](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#pusher-channels) we just need

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=your-pusher-app-id
PUSHER_APP_KEY=your-pusher-key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=your-pusher-secret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

`host` and `port` it's doesn't matter if you don't add to the pusher options `broadcasting.php` because pusher has publish they own way on their server. but if you have own websocket you must add `host` and `port` because websocket need this.

Comment: I am using laravel websockets package with pusher credentials (api key, app id, secret etc). I mean I am using pusher credentials but actually not pusher. Instead of pusher I am using laravel websocket package which uses pusher credentials. Do I need host in this case ?

Comment: it's doesn't matter if you don't add host for this case. So you don't need host

Comment: i mean you don't need to change the host. based on this documentation [link](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/pusher) the default host value is 127.0.0.1 so you don't need to change this value

Comment: When trying from live server getting an error like  "Pusher error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 6001" but works in local

Comment: have you start websocket server? you can use supervisor to running websocket server in production server

Comment: No I haven't start. That might be the issue. I am checking

Comment: Can you tell me how to use supervisor with laravel or provide any documentation ? I am using hostinger.

Comment: you can see this documentation about [supervisor](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/starting). i don't have experience with hostinger. but you need to know about your hosting. it is shared hosting/vps/something else? because if you're using shared hosting you need to contact Hostinger to provide supervisor on your hosting.